# error using django-admin with django-mssql

Tags: django, django-admin, django-mssql

I am using django 1.6 with django-mssql

My django admin site works perfectly except for one part.

Whenever I click an "add user" link or otherwise navigate to /admin/auth/user/add I get the following error

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', u'Cannot issue SAVE TRANSACTION when there is no active transaction.', None, 0, -2147467259), None)
Command:
SAVE TRANSACTION [s3612_x1]
Parameters:
[]
```

I've tried various seetings in my database config such as "use_mars": true but there has been no change.

I am able to create users in code by using the User model without issue.

I have not encountered this error anywhere else.

Comment: I used django and sql server with django-pyodbc-azure and I have no problems [git django-pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True  for my db connection, which I should have been doing anyway.